# Custom Task needs to be executed when gradle build is executed

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface

I am working on Java/JNI project. Under parent, I have different modules for java and C codebase.Java module needs to generate JNI header file. Since, I couldn't find any existing task/plugin that supported javah, so I wrote my custom task for javah to generate JNI interface. So, when I do 

`gradle javah`

I am getting the desired output.

1. However, I want that whenever I invoke `gradle build`, it should also execute javah task once either after classes are generated or build task ends.
2. Also, is it possible to generate the shared libraries in such a mixed project when I just do `gradle build`? Currently, I have to do `gradle <project-name>SharedLibrary`

Comment: Well, you can `dependsOn(compileJava)`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

***Part 1***: You can use `finalizedBy` on `task1` to execute `task2` after `task1` completes. For your case, you can try the following:

```
// 'javah' will be executed after 'classes' task executes.
classes.finalizedBy javah 

// Make 'javah' task depend on 'classes' task,
// so that when 'classes' task fails, 'javah' is not executed.  
javah.dependsOn classes

// Make 'build' depend on 'javah' task,
// so that executing 'build' task automatically executes 'javah'
build.dependsOn javah
```

***Part 2***: You can use `dependsOn` to wire up the `<project-name>SharedLibrary` task as follows:

```
build.dependsOn "${project.name}SharedLibrary"

// Assuming the SharedLibrary task needs to depend on 'javah' task
tasks["${project.name}SharedLibrary"].dependsOn javah
```

I'm assuming that the the SharedLibarary task name is dynamic, hence using a slightly different syntax for that task.

Comment: I have looked into finalizedBy and it will  enable javah to be called even if the task 'classes' fail. I want javah to be invoked when the task 'classes' is successful.

Comment: Edited my answer. This can be overcome by adding a dependency on `classes` for `javah` task. `javah.dependsOn classes`.